# Notificar os visitantes que uma pergunta está sendo respondida

Tags: novo-recurso, notificações

Às vezes acontece de uma pergunta ser fechada ou excluída enquanto se está escrevendo uma resposta pra mesma - causando frustração por não se poder postar o que escreveu e todo o esforço ir por água abaixo. Por isso quando vejo pessoas comentando sobre fechar ou negativando, já corro e faço um comentário dizendo que estou escrevendo uma resposta.

Mas hoje me aconteceu algo pior: uma resposta a [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78697/215) foi aceita e teve uma recompensa concedida enquanto eu escrevia uma resposta alternativa, sendo que a resposta aceita ainda estava "errada" por assim dizer (era uma pergunta sobre segurança, e o autor da resposta não estava ciente de uma certa vulnerabilidade, e respondeu dizendo que não havia nenhuma). Nesse caso não tinha sequer como eu saber que o autor da pergunta estava prestes a aceitar - pois não havia votos nem comentários em progresso dando a entender que alguma coisa estava acontecendo.

Gostaria de sugerir um novo recurso, não sei o quanto viável seria, mas que certamente iria ajudar muita gente (em particular os novatos que aceitam/excluem/abandonam uma pergunta em poucos minutos, após a primeira resposta/downvote/comentário negativo): gerar uma notificação pro autor da pergunta quando alguém começa a escrever uma resposta à mesma. Essa notificação - que poderia se valer do sistema já presente - não iria necessariamente pra caixa de entrada do usuário, mas ativaria algum elemento na pergunta pra sinalizar que ela está sendo respondida (da mesma forma que um voto dado atualiza o contador imediatamente, sem precisar recarregar a página).

Se acharem que esse tipo de coisa vale a pena e/ou é viável, posso sugerir isso no Metão (se é que isso já não foi feito antes; nunca vi nada a respeito sendo sugerido antes). E mesmo que seja impraticável fazer isso nos primeiros minutos de vida da pergunta (em que a atividade na mesma tende a ser maior) poderia se ter um intervalo mínimo de tempo a partir do qual as notificações começam a ser feitas.

Comment: Você deve ter morrido de raiva hein? rs.. Isso que ainda faltavam 4 dias para encerrar o período de destaque devido a recompensa da pergunta

Comment: @Math Meh! Faz parte... Pra mim o pior - já que segurança é um dos meus assuntos favoritos, apesar de eu estar longe de ser um expert nisso - é uma resposta que diz que certo problema não existe, estando bem destacada no topo, levando a quem não olhar com atenção a achar que aquilo está certo. Não entenda mal, a resposta é boa, eu mesmo votei positivo nela, e pra te falar a verdade até achei que era mesmo por aí. Foi só quando fui fazer um *background research* pra ver se havia algo a acrescentar é que me deparei com os problemas na mesma (i.e. eu próprio estava ignorante até ver a pergunta).

Comment: jeje, tenho uma resposta aberta aqui tem mais de uma hora... acho que nem vou terminar hoje! (ps: já vi isso sugerido no Metão mais de uma vez)

Comment: Supondo que isso seja implementado, alguém comece a responder uma pergunta sua e você receba a notificação sobre o fato. Mas, então, esse alguém desiste de responder (isso é uma opção possível!). O que acontece nesse caso? Você recebe outra notificação de que não há mais ninguém respondendo a pergunta? Não vai ser um tanto "chato"?

Comment: Talvez seja mais interessante ter na própria pergunta uma indicação numérica e *visível a todos* sobre o número de usuários preparando respostas naquele momento.

Comment: Acho uma ótima ideia. Contudo cheira-me que será um bocado "caro" de fazer isso.

Comment: Chegou o cara do UX aqui, agora o assunto ficou sério :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Acho que não me expressei bem, o que eu quis dizer com "Essa notificação (...) não iria necessariamente pra caixa de entrada do usuário, mas ativaria algum elemento na pergunta pra sinalizar que ela está sendo respondida" foi basicamente isso (uma indicação na própria pergunta).

Comment: @JorgeB. mas salvará muitas vidas.

Comment: Eu que não prestei a devida atenção nos detalhes do texto (embora a palavra "notificação" tenha realmente ajudado na confusão). Bom, desculpe. :) Ainda assim, eu concordo que seria algo útil.